# Reading from Linked Server and deleting on local DB

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have 2 similar tables on different databases. I already linked the remote DB and set it's data access to 'True'.

However I can't get the following query to work

```
GO
USE LOCALDB
GO
DELETE from [dbo].[TableA]
 WHERE [dbo].[TableA].[UniqueField] = (SELECT [UniqueField] FROM [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].[TableA])
GO
```

This query doesn't give me any error but then again it doesn't delete the entry where there is a match on the UniqueField. I'm quite blocked at the moment and this is the only query I've thought of that doesn't prompt an error.

EDIT: The query says 0 rows affected.

Thanks in advance,

EtonB.

Comment: Does it do nothing? Error? Timeout?

Comment: Does SELECT [UniqueField] FROM REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].[TableA]  return rows?

Comment: @gbn: It says 0 rows affected, even though checking the DB shows that there's obviously matching fields.

Comment: Also does SELECT * from [dbo].[TableA]
 WHERE [dbo].[TableA].[UniqueField] = (SELECT [UniqueField] FROM [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].[TableA]) return rows

Comment: = (SELECT [UniqueField] FROM [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].[TableA]) must return one value

Comment: @Conrad Frix: the first query returns the 1 unique value I'm looking for. The second query executes successfully but the result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thoughts...

I would consider loading a table variable locally and then deleting using that. This will stop any chance of a distributed txn starting which can happen for local write actions using data from a remote server.

Is UniqueField varchar and "collation compatible"? Or not and needs COLLATE. That is, perhaps the query is working as expected but the match is down to CASE.

What does this return?

```
SELECT [UniqueField] FROM [REMOTESERVER].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].[TableA]
```

Does it work for some values but not all? Exact datatype match? etc...

Comment: That query returns the 1 unique field I'm looking to match. It's a datetime field.

Comment: @Eton B.: are both columns datetime then? Are you sure the value exists on the local table down to the millisecond when you hardcode the select?

Comment: I just noticed there is a difference of 4 miliseconds.. that did the trick. Turns out my original query was OK. Thanks a lot!